# Pandas divide rows based on condition from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've 2 pandas dataframes like below:

```
**dataframe_1**

|col_1|col_2|col_3|
|a|2|2|
|b|4|4|
|a|2|2|
```

```
**dataframe_2**

|col_1|col_2|col_3|
|a|2|2|
|b|2|2|
```

How can i divide dataframe_1/dataframe_2 so that only col_1 a's in dataframe_1 are divided by col_1 a's in dataframe_2 and similar for b.

Expected output:

```
|col_1|col_2|col_3|
|a|1|1|
|b|2|2|
|a|1|1|
```

I've same number of columns in both tables.

**Edit:**
I've done this using iterrows on dataframe_1 and checking the col_1 and dividing with dataframe_2 values. I just wanted to see if there were other ways to doing it.

Scott Boston's answer works perfect.

Comment: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using set_index and letting pandas handle the data alignment:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('col_1')

df2 = df2.set_index('col_1')

(df1 / df2).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  col_1  col_2  col_3
0     a    1.0    1.0
1     a    1.0    1.0
2     b    2.0    2.0
```